# NSKeyedUnarchiver: iPhone .v. Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver

I'm doing:

```
NSString *current_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

NSString *string_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                    @"%@/filedstring", current_path];

my_string_ = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:string_path] retain];
```

The archived string is the text from a `UITextField` which we unarchive here. I've tried with and without `current_path`.

This all works fine when running in simulator (class member `NSString *my_string_` is not nil) but when run on my iPhone `my_string_` is nil.

Why is that?

---

Thanks for the quick responses all.

Adding to Jason Coco's answer, archive to and unarchive here:

```
NSString *library_path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,
                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *username_path = [library_path 
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches/filedstring"];
```

Comment: Quick tip: when you build paths using `NSString`, use the `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` method. See: http://bit.ly/fRKJZL

Comment: "Objective-C, iPhone, NSKeyedUnarchiver" is not a very descriptive title.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Can you recommend a title that would be more descriptive please? @ShaggyFrog: Yep, sure.

Comment: How about "NSKeyedUnarchiver fails when running on device but works fine on simulator" ? Objective-C and iPhone are not necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write into the main bundle on the phone, it's not allowed. That's why you don't find your archive there later. The simulator, since it actually runs on Mac OS X doesn't work this way, so it will actually write the file.

If you need to write something, you have to use one of the writeable paths available to your application. For more information, see the [iOS Application Programming Guide / The File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10). If you're going to do iOS Application Development, you should definitely read and understand this entire document.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. And you're right of course about reading the whole documents, I'm learning and reading as I go. I'm part time. The docs also make more sense to me the more experience I have.

Answer (score 0):

As @middaparka says, there is probably something wrong with that file. Here's how I would debug this problem:

First step,

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: string_path];
```

Second step,

```
NSError *err;
NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:string_path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
NSLog(@"Contents of string %@",tmp);
```

Once you've done those, you should have a much clearer idea why your `NSKeyedUnarchiver` is failing.
Also, check out NSString's `stringByAppendingPathComponent`: method.